# How to draw a hollow line with arrows in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

How do you draw an arrow like this in Inkscape? I tried:

1. draw a line
2. add an arrow to the end
3. make the whole thing wider
4. convert it to a path

and then played around with stroke and fill but nothing happened (using Inkscape on a Mac and it seems rather buggy), or actually - something happened - the same thing happened independently of if I used stroke or fill - the empty space in the arrow was filled.

(In the end I want to make a hollow object with arrows pointing in the same direction in both ends, something like >->)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the parts separately, align and combine to union:

[image]

Have all point snaps on, no other snaps!

1. Draw a rectangle.
2. Draw a triangle with the pen; it needs only 4 clicks; the 4th closes the triangle.
3. Drag the rectangle wider and lower, place it at the left side of the triangle (it snaps in the middle)
4. Combine (=Path > Union)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method.

Enable the grid, snap to grid, and add some guides.

Then draw the arrow with the Bézier tool

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way is to create it in MS Word and copy and paste-in-place into Inkscape. *(Insert→Shapes→Block Arrows)*

Comment: Easiest is a bi of a bad qualifier, easy according to what usecase. Your method is indeed easy. But only if you have word, the arrows in word are enough for you. etc. LIkewise, you can think of word symbols as library items, well yes but you can easily make inkscape library items so you only have to do it once. Im sure other library sites have arrow templates you can buy or dowload for free, this is also not much more complex than copy pasting form word.

Comment: I agree with @joojaa, and also I'm not sure that the MS Word Arrow will be pasted as a vector. At the moment I don't have the latest version of Word, and the image is pasted in Inkscape as a bitmap.